# Dynamic Thumbnails HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm doing some PSD to HTML for a friend except I'm far from great at it.
I'm trying to code the image below. When clicking on a different icon, you'd get a different timeline. I'm bad at Javascript so just wondering if that's doable in HTML/CSS and if so how ? Any basic examples ? Tutorials ?  (I'm not sure what I'm suppose to look for so my research hasn't been easy)

[image: timeline]

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do with HTML and CSS, but with Javascript it's easy. Here you can find the tutorial and examples: [Jquery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: Yes, I heard that before :) having a tiny tooltip (like when you hover on the purple line in the second block) took me three hours of work. (and I can't seem to figure out why it's not working on other places). I'll check it out though! Thanks.

Comment: Okay, that actually does look easy!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this the other day http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-image-slider-with-stylized-thumbnails which might be a stretch of the original intention of a radio button but a simple javascript-less solution for it, worth the try :)

Basically the idea is that you play with the selected states of the radio button, hide the elements on load and use the ':checked' pseudo selector to display them, since only one element in a radio group can be selected at a time, this gets the job done.

Again, this is a stretch of the original intention of the control but it's a cool hack indeed :)

Comment: I'll try this if the Javascript doesn't work. Thank you both for your answers!

Comment: This is not working in Internet Explorer.

Comment: This is more of a hack, not a real blown out solution, I would go with JS if I were you